# SQL QUERY to retrieve data from table

Tags: sql

```
user_id  assignment_ts            experiment_id   experiment_assignment
1        2019-01-06 12:00:05.000    1             test
1        2019-03-04 01:45:23.000    2             test
2        2019-01-07 03:45:12.000    1             control
3        2019-03-11 01:45:23.000    2             test
```

When did each experiment start?  Use the first instance of an experiment assignment to either test or control for an experiment to equate to when the experiment started.  Results should look like:

I am not able to put together a query for this question if i use distinct it is not working also and i can't seem to figure out how to do it???

Comment: You just want to get single row (first occurance) for each experiment for experiemnt_assignment test and control. Right?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? because there are specific solutions per DBMS for these types of queries.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER` can be used here, assuming your SQL database support it:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY experiment_id ORDER BY assignment_ts) rn
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE experiment_assignment IN ('test', 'control')
)

SELECT user_id, assignment_ts, experiment_id, experiment_assignment
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate function MIN:

```
SELECT experiment_id, MIN(assignment_ts) as startDate
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY experiment_id
```

assuming that what you are trying to get is the first assignment_ts date for each experiment_id.